# How can I get this Typescript typeguard to work in a generic-type context?

Tags: generics, typescript

The initialization of v2 below gives: `Type 'T[keyof T]' cannot be converted to type 'number'.`  What is wrong?

```
private func<T extends Object>(o:T, prop: keyof(T)): void {
    const val = o[prop]
    if ( typeof val === 'number' ) {
        const v2: number = val as number
    }
}
```

This works in a non-generic context, below, [UPDATE] but this isn't useful as a workaround, since callers may only use properties of Object itself.

```
private func2(o:Object, prop: keyof(Object)): void {
    const val = o[prop]
    if ( typeof val === 'number' ) {
        const v2: number = val as number
    }
}
```

This is a silly example that I extracted to focus on the problem; if a real context would help, let me know.

Comment: Do you have to cast it to a number? Isn't the type inferred?

Comment: @MuratK. The same error (with slightly different wording) occurs if I don't cast.  I included the cast because if I hadn't, I'd get comments that I should try it! ;-)

Comment: If anyone more expert can explain WHY the typeguard doesn't work in this case, I'd be grateful.  I'm wondering whether to write up an issue (bug report) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to typescript, but I it seems like you have to double cast it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736071/4467208)

```
  private func1<T extends Object>(o:T, prop: keyof(T)): void {
    const val = o[prop]
    if ( typeof val === 'number' ) {
        const v2: number = val as any as number
    }
```

Besides that you could use it like this maybe? I read it on the docs at least. [Section Index Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
private func<T extends Object, K extends keyof T>(o: T, prop: K): void {
    const val = o[prop]
    if (typeof val === 'number') {
        const v2 = val as any as number
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.